# How to know when user has a text entry control focused in other applications

Tags: c#

The purpose is for an on screen keyboard, I would like to know if the user has focused (clicked on or tabbed into) a control that allows text input so the keyboard can optionally automatically popup. I assume there is a windows message that I hook that gives me hWind of active controls when focus changes, then perhaps there is another pinvoke that alows me to check for control type based on hWind?, unfortunately thats the extent of my knowledge on the subject.

Comment: What kind of on-screen keyboard? The official osk.exe built-in to Windows uses Windows Accessibility and automation events to detect when an input has focus and can accept keyboard entry, but it isn't always reliable as third-party controls often do their own thing.

Comment: This is for my own, not MS's OSK.

Answer (score -1):

You can get just the event when something got the focus with the GotFocus event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx

You can apply it to all Forms.

Comment: "in other applications" being the operative phrase.

Comment: So it could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407631/is-there-windows-system-event-on-active-window-changed ?

Comment: How is that even remotely a duplicate, not even the same subject.

Comment: I think the description really fits your needs. The windows message you are looking for is [VM_ACTIVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: How does knowing what window is active accomplish my goal?

Comment: When you only want to get your keyboard active when you focussed the text box (not the form) you can use the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14393399/7658355

Comment: Thats cpp and still doesn't contain a solution beyond what I already speculated in that setting a window hook would likely be needed.